# How can i utter html formatted response in rasa

Tags: html, rasa-core

I need to send some HTML formatted response like Bold, Paragraph from rasa core to chatroom - react UI.

I have a custom action in rasa core where i need to send some formatted text as response .

```
  dispatcher.utter_message("<b>Hello world</b>)
```

Answer (score 1):

The message is interpreted by the [output channel](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/messaging-and-voice-channels/) of Rasa. So you either have to implement a custom output channel which send messages to the user as plain text or you have to parse the response from Rasa in the frontend. The community in the [Rasa forum](https://forum.rasa.com) might also be able to help you.